Yolov8 CNN model in Shiny mixing R and Python
I want to create a Shiny app using R and Python cause the Yolov8 model was developed in Python. But, I try to use my app calling a *py code (yolov8_loader.py) in my app directory and it doesn't work.
In my example, I try:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rsconnect)
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# Create a py_env environment and install: pip install ultralytics
setwd('C:/Users/IFMT/anaconda3/envs/py_env')
renv::init()
Sys.setenv(RENV_PATHS_CACHE = 'C:/Users/IFMT/anaconda3/envs/py_env')
renv::use_python(type = 'conda', name = 'py_env')
# 

#Create a new Python file, e.g., yolov8_loader.py, with the following content inside the py_env environment:
# import ultralytics as yolo
#
#   def load_model():
#   model = yolo.YOLO("https://github.com/ultralytics/assets/releases/download/v0.0.0/yolov8n.pt")
# return model

# Load the Python module
yolov8_loader <- source_python("yolov8_loader.py")

# Import the load_model function
load_model <- yolov8_loader$load_model

# Load the model
model <- load_model()

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello YOLOv8!"),
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input: File upload
      fileInput("image_path", label = "Input a JPEG image")
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # Output: Histogram ----
      textOutput(outputId = "prediction"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "image")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  image <- reactive({
    req(input$image_path)
    jpeg::readJPEG(input$image_path$datapath)
  })
  
  output$prediction <- renderText({
    img <- image() %>% 
      array_reshape(., dim = c(1, dim(.), 1))
    
    # Use the loaded model to make predictions
    prediction <- model(img)
    paste0("The predicted class is ", prediction)
  })
  
  output$image <- renderPlot({
    plot(as.raster(image()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


But the yolov8_loader object is always:

NULL


Please, any help with it?
Thanks in advance,
Alexandre

I see what's going on here. You're trying to use Python code in an R Shiny app, which is a great idea! However, there are a few issues with your approach.
Issue 1: source_python doesn't work as you expect
source_python is not meant to execute Python code in the same way that source executes R code. Instead, it loads a Python module into the R environment, allowing you to access its functions and variables. However, it doesn't execute the Python code in the file.
Issue 2: reticulate doesn't automatically import Python variables
When you use source_python to load a Python module, you need to explicitly import the variables or functions you want to use in R. In your case, you're trying to access the model variable from the image_classification.py file, but you haven't imported it.
Issue 3: detection_model is not defined
You're trying to use reticulate::detection_model as if it were a function, but it's not defined anywhere in your code.
To fix these issues, you'll need to modify your approach. Here's a suggested solution:
Step 1: Create a Python module with a function to load the model
Create a new Python file, e.g., yolov8_loader.py, with the following content:
import ultralytics as yolo

def load_model():
    model = yolo.YOLO("https://github.com/ultralytics/assets/releases/download/v0.0.0/yolov8n.pt")
    return model

This file defines a load_model function that loads the YOLOv8 model.
Step 2: Load the Python module in R and import the function
In your R code, load the yolov8_loader module using source_python:
library(reticulate)

# Load the Python module
yolov8_loader <- source_python("yolov8_loader.py")

# Import the load_model function
load_model <- yolov8_loader$load_model

Step 3: Use the imported function to load the model
Now, you can use the load_model function to load the YOLOv8 model:
# Load the model
model <- load_model()

Step 4: Modify your Shiny app to use the loaded model
Update your Shiny app to use the loaded model:
server <- function(input, output) {
  image <- reactive({
    req(input$image_path)
    jpeg::readJPEG(input$image_path$datapath)
  })
  
  output$prediction <- renderText({
    img <- image() %>% 
      array_reshape(., dim = c(1, dim(.), 1))
    
    # Use the loaded model to make predictions
    prediction <- model(img)
    paste0("The predicted class is ", prediction)
  })
  
  output$image <- renderPlot({
    plot(as.raster(image()))
  })
}

This should fix the issues you're facing. Note that you'll need to modify the image_classification.py file to define a function that takes an image as input and returns a prediction, and then import that function in your R code.

Thank you very much for your explanation, but despite I install the pip install ultralytics in C:/Users/IFMT/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate, when I try `yolov8_loader <- source_python("yolov8_loader.py")  the yolov8_loader object is
NULL

I changed my original code based in our help to explain the problem better.
